# How to calculate the expression of a datatable

Tags: c#

Current Code:

```
foreach (Expressions e in expressionObj)
{
   if ((e.Expression != null) && (e.ColumnName != null))
   {
      newtable1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(e.ColumnName, typeof(decimal), e.Expression));
   }   
}
```

I have an expression as ID+ID which is to be added as new column in the datatable as SUM-ID where ID=2, but the result got is 22 instead of 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(decimal)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SUM-ID", typeof(decimal), "ID + ID"));
var row = dt.NewRow();
row["ID"] = 2;
dt.Rows.Add(row);
var val = dt.Rows[0]["SUM-ID"];
```

Result: `val` is `4` as expected.
Let's try something else:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("SUM-ID", typeof(decimal), "ID + ID"));
var row = dt.NewRow();
row["ID"] = "2";
dt.Rows.Add(row);
var val = dt.Rows[0]["SUM-ID"];
```

Result: `val` is `22`

Conclusion: Your `ID` column is of type string but it needs to be a numeric type instead otherwise string concatenation is used.

**Update**: If you cannot (or don't want to) set the datatype of the column then you can use `Convert` inside the expression: `2 * Convert(ID, 'System.Int32')`

Comment: @ChrableWue- The problem here is, I'm using a XML file and the data from the XML in set into the datatable. On the coressponding table, I'm trying to calculate the expression. It should be a generic code and how can I set numeric type to it.